# Outlook 2016 how to copy a lot of messages to another folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I need to copy all my Inbox messages (local pst) into a new account's inbox (imap, outlook 365)

I am using Office 365 (2016 version currently)

There are a lot of emails (more than 10gb).
From my reading it seems that the best suggestion is to make a rule to copy the messages, and execute the rule manually, and make my rule do 1 year at a time (I have 6 years).

The problem with this method is that my outlook will completely hang up when running a rule so I can't do anything in my outlook while a rule is running.
And it takes hours to run.
Also sometimes it just bombs up and doesnt complete the year (at best I get 2 months in a go)

So my question is if there is a smarter way to do this? Can my rule be scripted to execute in the background?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion in to leave the 10 Gb files as it is.. and load it as a separate folder in outlook.

Account Settings > Data Files > Add : Choose the pst file.

Comment: but I specifically want to copy data into another folder

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but IMHO, It hangs due to the magnitude of the files that is handled.. || "to make a rule to copy the messages, and execute the rule manually" seems to be a good idea.. but may I suggest you to.. open the old pst. > maka a "new" folder inside the old pst.. > choose about 300 MB of emails.. > "dump" it there, upon success (no hang) > "dump" it in your new archive. || if 300MB emails chunk doesn't hang your PC you may go for bigger chunk. ( :

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using rules, I just right clicked , Copy Folder, selected OST inbox.
Froze up my outlook for an hour, but thats all. everything moved across perfectly.

not what I was looking for but I suppose it did the job

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Open the PST file in Outlook.
2. Right click the PST file and select "Data File Properties"
3. Click Advanced button. Click "Compact Now" to compact the PST file.
4. Try moving the folders in the PST file one by one to the destination IMAP account via dragging & dropping.